# Mac OS X rosmake rviz failed to load wxPython.rdmanifest

Tags: rviz, macos, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody!

After finally being able to install ROS Electric on a Mac OS X Lion, I am facing the following problem when attempting to build rviz:

```
rosmake --rosdep-install rviz
```

results in:

```
[ rosmake ] rosdep install failed: Failed to load a rdmanifest from http://mirror.ausparc.com/ros/sourcedeps/wxPython.rdmanifest, and no alternate URI given
```

I have manually checked the URI and it appears to be dead. Any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance.
Martin.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42427/mac-os-x-rosmake-rviz-failed-to-load-wxpython.rdmanifest/) by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5625 on 2012-08-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2012-08-27**:
Duh! I am so dumb!! The solution to this is on the wiki (section 3.6): http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/OSX/Homebrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution should be in an answer, so that it shows up as answered on the main page:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/OSX/Homebrew#wxPython_fails_to_install_due_to_ausparc.com_dependency

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2012-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0